# Read data from USB Virtual COM in STM32 Nucleo-F767ZI [Ubuntu]

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I have written a program to stream data through USB port CN13, using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk--a4K497M). I am not able to see the data on the USB Virtual COM Port. When I connect the ST-LINK and Virtual COM port, there is only one USB Device, ST-LINK, getting recognized when trying `dmesg | grep usb`. I have seen many basic [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk--a4K497M) on YouTube which shows the Virtual COM USB Port detection happens without installing any drivers. STM32 MOOCs uses Windows but I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I have tried some of the stack overflow [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597612/stm32-usb-vcp-virtual-com-port). Could anyone guide me as to how to overcome this issue?

Comment: The virtual serial connection should appear as `/dev/ttyACM0` (or similar). Is such a device present? In order to see the serial output, you need to use a terminal program. What kind of program do you use and can it connect to the `/dev/tty...` device?

Comment: Yes, I get /dev/ttyACM0 , which corresponds to ST-LINK, when checked via dmesg...but not to Virtual COM Port...

Comment: What do you mean by "but not to Virtual COM Port"? /dev/ttyACM0 is virtual serial port (or COM port in Windows terms). And again: what terminal program do you use or plan to use?

Comment: There are two USB ports in Nucleo-144 F767ZI board, one is for flashing the program which is detected as ST-LINK and other is for communication, which is CN13 pin , which is supposed to be detected as Virtual COM Port in my ubuntu. I am using the default terminal to see the USB devices and to read the data serially, I am planning to use the application CoolTerm

Comment: I am writing a simple program to send hello world string when I switch on the stm32 and try to read data from the USB port... I followed the example link mentioned above, but I am not able to see the data stream...

Comment: Now I understand. You have written custom code for creating a "virtual COM port" in addition to the port provided by the ST-Link. I guess the problem is in your code. So add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to use the USB port for communication. This is done using STM32CubeIDE

1. Launch STMCubeIDE software.
2. Select the USB_OTG_FS and set as device only mode.
3. Then in middleware tab select the Class for FS IP as Communication device class(virtual com port).
4. Set the clock frequency for USB as 48MHz.
5. Generate the project.
6. Read the usbd_cdc_if.c file
7. Include the usbd_cdc_if.h in the main and send some data using `CDC_Transmit_FS`
8. In Ubuntu, open a terminal and search for two ACM ports using `ls /dev/tty`, ACM0 and ACM1/ACM2 (which are STLINK-V3 and Virtual ComPort)
9. Test using serial terminal (like Serial Monitor of Arduino IDE).