# STM32cube USB VCP doesn't appear on Windows 10

Tags: c, usb, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to figure out how to enable USB VCP functionality on my STM32F103-based Blue Pill board. In following [Shawn Hymell's guide](https://shawnhymel.com/1795/getting-started-with-stm32-nucleo-usb-virtual-com-port/) and attempting to troubleshoot with [this other SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594411/3339274), I currently have the following (*minified*) `main.c`: (*[Git Gist with full file](https://gist.github.com/neilbalch/719ddb38c225f5465789872843b7a93a)*)

```c
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char msg[50];
  uint8_t state = 0;

  HAL_StatusTypeDef ret_status;
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  sprintf(msg, "Restart!\n");
  ret_status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  while (1) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, state ? GPIO_PIN_RESET : GPIO_PIN_SET);
      sprintf(msg, "Hello World! LED State: %d\n", state);
      ret_status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      ret_status = CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg));

      state = state == 1 ? 0 : 1;
      HAL_Delay(500);
  }
}
```

I can tell that the program is (*otherwise*) running properly because the UART adapter shows that `char msg` is being output at the correct interval and the board's `PC13` LED is flashing. However, my Windows 10 computer doesn't even recognize that there is a USB device plugged in, only showing the FTDI adapter's COM port and my STLink v2:

[image]

As of now, I've tried the following potential fixes from [the other SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594411/3339274):

- In `usbd_cdc_if.c` set `APP_RX_DATA_SIZE 64` and `APP_TX_DATA_SIZE 64`
- In `usbd_cdc_if.c` add below code to the CDC_Control_FS() function:

```c
case CDC_SET_LINE_CODING:
  tempbuf[0]=pbuf[0];
  tempbuf[1]=pbuf[1];
  tempbuf[2]=pbuf[2];
  tempbuf[3]=pbuf[3];
  tempbuf[4]=pbuf[4];
  tempbuf[5]=pbuf[5];
  tempbuf[6]=pbuf[6];
  break;
case CDC_GET_LINE_CODING:
  pbuf[0]=tempbuf[0];
  pbuf[1]=tempbuf[1];
  pbuf[2]=tempbuf[2];
  pbuf[3]=tempbuf[3];
  pbuf[4]=tempbuf[4];
  pbuf[5]=tempbuf[5];
  pbuf[6]=tempbuf[6];
  break;
```

- Add `HAL_Delay(1000);` before the first instance of calling `CDC_Transmit_FS`
- Confirmed that the USB cable I'm using has data lines
- Setting `Minimum Heap Size` to `0x1000` in the CubeMX Device Configuration Tool

Has anyone else seen something like this before? I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: Check the cable :) Your main rather not sufficient. You need to set clock initialize hal, gpio etcetc.

Comment: Another problem - check pullup resistors on D+ & D- lines. Many BP have them wrong

Comment: Well, not sure if this helps, but I've done some more digging and found that the check for `TxState != 0` in `CDC_Transmit_FS` is being triggered, resulting in the return code `USBD_BUSY`. I don't exactly know how to interpret this...

Comment: Hrm, @0___________, what should they be?

Comment: Also, my minification of the `main.c` file removed those lines. All of the normal config functions are there and being called.

Comment: Simply generate the empty project in CubeMx ***without*** your changes and try. I use it all the time without any problems.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what the resistor values should be. I measure `R10 = 10k` and `R9 = R11 = 20`

Comment: @0___________ Here is a copy of my full `main.c` https://gist.github.com/neilbalch/719ddb38c225f5465789872843b7a93a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my problem was far more simple than I thought. In my infinite wisdom, I decided to try this on a breadboard I'd previously been using for CANbus testing, without disconnecting the CAN circuit.

[image] (*[ref](http://www.reblag.dk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/The-Generic-STM32F103-Pinout-Diagram.pdf)*)

This was never going to work, as the CANbus pins I'd been trying to use (*and left plugged in*) share functionality with the USB port. The VCP immediately showed up and worked after I unplugged the breadboard wires I'd connected to `PA11` and `PA12`. I feel dumb, but relieved, right now.